# Is there a well defined notion corresponding to the "opposite" of a particular probability mass function/distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

The intuition behind the use of the word "opposite" in the title is that the "opposite" of a unimodal distribution with the mode at zero would be a distribution with a trough at zero and probability increasing as one moved away from zero. Sort of turning the graph of the distribution upside down. Another conception would be that the "opposite" of one distibution would be a distribution that when mixed equally with the first would yield a uniform distribution. Is there something in probability theory that makes this idea precise? I am not sure what the right key words are to be searching for.

Background: I will be doing a probability learning experiment, and I want to provide participants with samples that are the "opposite" of their current estimate in the sense above. Participants would be allowed to revise their estimate of the generating distribution, and would see new samples, again "opposite" their revision. I would like to be able to argue that the optimal solution is to converge to a uniform distribution.

Comment: By your description the opposite of a standard Gaussian distribution would have to have nonzero probability density everywhere away from the origin, but this is impossible.

Comment: Is there something equivalent or similar in the circumstance where the domain is finite?

Comment: @brittUWaterloo the integral of $\alpha - f$ is unlikely $1$ if $f\ge 0$ and $\int f =1$.

Comment: But it is the shape that seems the key - we can always normalize the magnitude. For concreteness lets assume a multinomial distribution with some finite number of options, e.g. 40. The we can think of the multinomial with all outcomes equally probable as a vector pointing in 40-D space, and any other distribution doing the same. Those two vectors define a plane with an angle \alpha between them. Could we define the "opposite" distribution as the vector lying in the same plane rotated \alpha past the uniform? Is there something like this notion I can be pointed towards?